# Change color of groups in xyplot - archetypal analysis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dimensionality-reduction, archetypes

I have an xyplot that plots archetypes of a umap plot like below. Every single one of these points belongs to a timepoint stored in a list. How do I change the color of these points to reflect time accordingly?

```
The head(umapped$layout) is

 [,1]      [,2]
1 -0.9905974  5.016414
2 -2.0759074  2.087989
3  0.6921594 -1.780826
4 -2.9713005  8.018761
5 -3.7351895  7.015174
6 -3.6934716  5.780606
```

and I found the archetypes through

```
archetypes(umapped$layout, 3)->a
```

This is how I am plotting:

```
xyplot(a, umapped$layout, chull = chull(umapped$layout))
```

This is the head of the list containing the time info for every data point.

```
head(my.time)

[1] "3" "3" "3" "3" "3" "7"
```

Is there a way I can convert this plot into a ggplot?

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: `ggplot2` is designed to work most fluidly where data for the plot (or at least data for each layer) is held in a single data frame. Can you combine whatever data might be in `a`, `umapped$layout`, and `meta.data$Time` into a single data frame? Then it'd be very straightforward.

Comment: @JonSpring my problem is ```a``` is an archetypes object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include colors all we need to do is add my.time as an extra argument in the xyplot so

```
xyplot(a, umapped$layout, chull = chull(umapped$layout),my.time)
```

fixes the issue.